# Intellij reformat file without inserting space between lines

Tags: intellij-idea, format

Say I have the following lines:

```
foo();
bar();

int main() {
}
```

Intellij reformats it so that it becomes:

```
foo();

bar();

...
```

How do I make it so that it does **not** add the annoying whitespace between `foo()` and `bar()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java it can be configured in File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java, Blank Lines, Around method:

[image: around method]